# Why there is no -2 reputation for an tag wiki edit when the tag is removed?

Tags: discussion, reputation, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

When we (users below 2k reputation) edit a post, we get +2 reputation when the edit is accepted. Later on, if the post gets deleted, then we lose the 2 reputation for that edit.

When we edit a tag wiki, we get +2 for each edited wiki part. Later on, when the tag is removed by the system, our reputation is not affected. Why doesn't our reputation get reversed (by -2 or -4) in this case?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Because current behavior is that when a tag gets destroyed, its wiki and excerpt remain intact, as in the posts themselves do not get deleted along with the tag. Since they are not deleted and are just lingering out in the void of Stack Exchange partial-existence, the reputation from suggested edits on them does not get removed. This oddness [causes other issues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148928/orphaned-tag-wiki-edits-have-broken-activity-entries) as well.

Comment: So how about removing them completely to avoid all these oddities? Does that have any side effects?

Comment: @Amal I suggested that very thing in the question I linked.